# my question was marked as opinion based - I edited it - is it still opinion based

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question [How would you affect bulk DNA gene therapy for a human?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/would-bulk-dna-gene-therapy-of-a-human-be-possible)

I had worded the question in a way that might have been open to interpretations about the seriousness of the question or whether it's possible to answer.  I reworded the question.

Is this new version still considered opinion-based?  If so, can you explain why?

Comment: It is still quite broad.

Comment: some questions are broad.  It was put on hold because it's opinion-based.  Is it still "opinion-based"  - why?  http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/344/why-do-we-age-or-do-we-have-a-theory-of-senescence is also broad.

Comment: I asked this question [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20502073#20502073). It may not be opinion based but it is still broad. We don't have any mechanism to change the close reason post close.

Comment: how is this too broad?  That claim seems very subjective and "opinion-based".  You have gene therapy which is real science and I'm asking how to apply it in bulk.  It's a very specific question with answers that could range from "you can't" to "I don't know" to "you need to a specific gene therapy mechanism for each gene that needs to be modified"  etc.

Comment: What is broad: anything that cannot be explained in a few paragraphs. It is not a claim. I can answer that question but I would have to write an entire article on it.

Comment: The problem is that this question was put on hold for being opinion based. You think that its also too broad. Perhaps the other moderators that marked as "opinion-based" don't agree. I would suggest that you remove the hold and then mark as suggest to put on hold for being too broad. If others agree then it will be on hold/closed the that reason. But if others don't agree then the question will be available for answers.

Comment: Once having voted to close a user is not allowed to revote for closure after reopen.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - ok - I understand.  Is there some mechanism to bring this up with the other's that marked to closed?     If I add a comment on the question, will they get a notice?

Comment: You can actually edit your question further to make it precise. That would be the best solution :)

Comment: @WYSIWYG seems like it was unblocked - thanks for your help and education!

Comment: I voted to reopen but you should make some improvements

Comment: thanks - what would make it more precise?  I made many changes and I'm not sure what other changes would make it better.  I really do think it's an interesting question and problem and would like to get answers.

Comment: A precise question would be to ask about experimental strategies to make multiple simultaneous genome edits in a cell. Avoid any reference to attainment of immortality. You are also asking multiple questions there; you should focus on only one issue.

Comment: ok - thanks for the tips.  I was trying to given examples to explain how drastic of DNA changes we might be talking about.